# Adding a TapGestureRecognizer to a Xaml Grid - Doesn't work?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Xamarin Forms 2.5**

I have a `ListView` with a custom `GroupHeaderTemplate` that renders nicely:

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <templates:SummaryCellHeader />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

The `GroupHeaderTemplate` has a `Grid` with a `TapGestureRecognizer`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ListHeaderTappedCommand}" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>
```

The `TapGestureRecognizer` never fires. This template works if used outside a `ListViewHeader`.

Are `TapGestureRecognizers` allowed in a ListView `GroupHeaderTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the binding context for the header is the data the list is showing, not the view model.

Give your list view a name then use that to change the binding context source for the command.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPeople}"
          IsGroupingEnabled="true"
          x:Name="PersonList">

<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference PersonList}, BindingContext.ListHeaderTappedCommand}" />
</Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Steve Chadbourne. Seems you can also put a Command on the Key if the Key is a complex object rather than a simple string:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0"  >
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Key.ListHeaderTappedCommand}" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

The benefit is that you get a reference to the Header POCO used to create the list. This is helpful to determine the action to take onHeaderClick